# updateChildren not updating the children?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am checking whether the username exists or not during the sign up procedure. The only problem is that my **childupdates2** is not being added to the **Usernames** folder? The first **childUpdate** is added properly but the second **childUpdate2** doesn't. It just doesnt update my **Usernames** folder?

```
 final DatabaseReference Userref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    username_check_query = Userref.child("Usernames").orderByChild("username").equalTo(mUsernameView.getText().toString());
    usernameChildEvent = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.getValue() == null){

                ScoreClass scoreClass = new ScoreClass(10000, mUsernameView.getText().toString());
                Map<String, Object> scoredata = scoreClass.toMap();
                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                childUpdates.put("Users/" + user.getUid(), scoredata);
                Userref.updateChildren(childUpdates);


                Username username = new Username(mUsernameView.getText().toString());
                Map<String, Object> userdata = username.toMap();
                Map<String, Object> childUpdates2 = new HashMap<>();
                childUpdates2.put("/Usernames/" + user.getUid(), userdata);
                Userref.updateChildren(childUpdates2);
           }
           else {
                    // other code
            }
            username_check_query.removeEventListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
username_check_query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(usernameChildEvent);
```

Here is the database structure.

[image: database structure]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show here your actual database structure of firebase ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya I have added the structure.

Comment: why you are not using model class ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya tried that as well. Still its not updating the "Usernames" folder

Comment: You're not checking the result of the update, so it's hard to say why it's failing. Do you have security rules in place that might allow the first update but block the second?

Comment: @TravisChristian How can i check the result of the update? And no i did not change the security rules.

Comment: See answer by qbix below and the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your results.  Add a completion listener to see what the status of the update is:

```
    Userref.updateChildren(childUpdates2, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if (databaseError == null) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: success");
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onComplete: fail", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Also verify that `username.toMap()` produces a non-empty map:

```
    Map<String, Object> userdata = username.toMap();
    if (userdata.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Oops! No data");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "userdata=" + userdata);
    }
```

Comment: Good one.
For future reference: [Detect errors when writing a value to Android](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database#t=201608311732467227622)